# video rotation using AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction

Tags: iphone, ios, avfoundation, cgaffinetransform, avmutablecomposition

I am merging multiple videos and I want to detect which ones are in portrait mode and rotate them in landscape so that all movies are in landscape mode... I have done everything and works perfectly except the actual rotate, I guess it's something with the center of the rotation or a composed rotation.

```
        AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction *videoTrackLayerInstruction = [AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction videoCompositionLayerInstructionWithAssetTrack:compositionVideoTrack];

        if([[AppDelegate sharedInstance] orientationForTrack:avAsset] == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait)
        {
            CGAffineTransform rotation = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/2);
            //CGAffineTransform translateToCenter = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(640, 480);
            //CGAffineTransform mixedTransform = CGAffineTransformConcat(rotation, translateToCenter);
            [videoTrackLayerInstruction setTransform:rotation atTime:nextClipStartTime];
        }
        else if([[AppDelegate sharedInstance] orientationForTrack:avAsset] == UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
        {
            CGAffineTransform rotation = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI/2);
            [videoTrackLayerInstruction setTransform:rotation atTime:nextClipStartTime];
        }
        else if([[AppDelegate sharedInstance] orientationForTrack:avAsset] == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft)
        {
            CGAffineTransform rotation = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI);
            [videoTrackLayerInstruction setTransform:rotation atTime:nextClipStartTime];
        }
        else if([[AppDelegate sharedInstance] orientationForTrack:avAsset] == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight)
        {
            [videoTrackLayerInstruction setTransform:CGAffineTransformIdentity atTime:nextClipStartTime];
        }
```

How can I rotate them properly? I have tried multiple sources but nothing rotates them as they should. I am not interested in the 320 scale fit solution I want the video to keep as much resolution as possible before exporting using AVAssetExportSession.

A solution like this:

```
CGAffineTransform rotationTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degreesToRadians(90.0));
CGAffineTransform rotateTranslate = CGAffineTransformTranslate(rotateTransform,320,0);
```

won't suit my needs as I have tried it. Do you have any ideas? Some help will be pretty much appreciated.

Comment: did you ever figure this out? I am stuck with the exact same problem. Please post answer if you know

Comment: nope sorry... still not working as it should :(